# Question about an ATTINY85, SPI over USI and the ability to read an MCP23S08

Tags: spi, attiny85

I was hoping for a little help in writing a function so that I get an understanding basic SPI over USI on an ATTINY85.

I followed a YouTube tutorial on writing bits and blinking an LED with a ATTINY85 on an SPI MCP23S08. I've already changed somethings to make it more "familiar" and easy to help me remember why things work the way they do. So, it still blinks the LEDs, but I think I understand why/how it works for that. Below is that code:

```
/* ATMEL ATTINY85
   Pin 1 is /RESET
   
              +-\/-+
   ADC0 PB5  1|    |8  Vcc
   ADC3 PB3  2|    |7  PB2 ADC1 INT0
   ADC2 PB4  3|    |6  PB1 OCR0B
        GND  4|    |5  PB0 OCR0A
              +----+
 
 
   PB0 = MOSI
   PB1 = MISO
   PB2 = MOSI
   PB3 = CS
   
   LED on MCP23S08, GP0
*/
 
#define F_CPU 1000000UL // Setting micro to 1MHz
 
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
 
// MCP23S08 Registers (Table 1-2)
#define MCP23S08_IODIR      0x00
#define MCP23S08_IPOL       0x01
#define MCP23S08_GPINTEN    0x02
#define MCP23S08_DEFVAL     0x03
#define MCP23S08_INTCON     0x04
#define MCP23S08_IOCON      0x05
#define MCP23S08_GPPU       0x06
#define MCP23S08_INTF       0x07
#define MCP23S08_INTCAP     0x08
#define MCP23S08_GPIO       0x09
#define MCP23S08_OLAT       0x0A
#define MCP23S08_WRITE_REG  0x40    // 0 1 0 0 0 A1 A0 W, b01000000 or 0x40, see figure 1-5
#define MCP23S08_READ_REG   0x41    // 0 1 0 0 0 A1 A0 R, b01000001 or 0x41, see figure 1-5
 
// SS or CS (Slave Select or Chip Select)
#define SS_PIN PB3
#define DD_SS_PIN DDB3
 
 
// DO or MISO (Data Out, Master In Slave Out)
#define DO_PIN PB1
#define DD_DO_PIN DDB1
 
 
// DI or MOSI (Data In, Master Out Slave In)
#define DI_PIN PB0
#define DD_DI_PIN DDB0
 
 
// CLK (Clock)
#define CLK_PIN PB2
#define DD_CLK_PIN DDB2
 
 
void SPISetUp(void);
void setGPIO(uint8_t data);
void setIODIR(uint8_t data);
void WriteSPI(uint8_t data);
 
uint8_t mcp23s08_addr = 0x00;   // A0 is ground, A1 is ground
 
int main(void) {
    uint8_t mcp23s08_port = 0x00;
    uint8_t mcp23s08_direction = 0xff;      // make all GPIO pins be inputs (high bits)
    mcp23s08_addr = (mcp23s08_addr << 1);   // shift address over by 1 as the first bit is the R/W bit (see figure 1-5)
    mcp23s08_direction |= (1 << 2);         // make GPIO 2 be an input (high bit)
    mcp23s08_direction &= ~(1 << 0);        // make GPIO 0 be an output (low bit)
    // mcp23s08_port |= (1 << 2);           // Set bit 2 to high to enable pull-up on GPIO 2
    SPISetUp();
    setIODIR(mcp23s08_direction);       // make GPIO pins be outputs
    setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);             // turn off LED
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) {
        mcp23s08_port |= (1 << 0);  // Set bit 0 to high to turn on GPIO 0
        setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn on LED
        _delay_ms(500);
        mcp23s08_port &= ~(1 << 0); // Set bit 0 to low to turn off GPIO 0
        setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn off LED
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}
 
 
void SPISetUp() {
    // outputs
    DDRB |= (1<<DD_DO_PIN) | (1<<DD_SS_PIN) | (1<<DD_CLK_PIN);
    // inputs
    DDRB &= ~(1<<DD_DI_PIN);
    // SPI Config
    USICR = (1<<USIWM0);    // USIWM1 0, USIWM0 1 is SPI
    // SS_PIN on, and DI_PIN enable pull-up
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN) | (1<<DI_PIN);
}
 
void setIODIR(uint8_t data) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_WRITE_REG | mcp23s08_addr);   // Slave Address
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_IODIR);       // IODIR Address
    WriteSPI(data);                 // IODIR Direction
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
}
 
void setGPIO(uint8_t data) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_WRITE_REG | mcp23s08_addr);   // Slave Address
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_GPIO);        // GPIO Address
    WriteSPI(data);                 // GPIO Values (0 or 1, ON or OFF)
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
}
 
void WriteSPI(uint8_t data) {
    // Load USI Data Register with data to transmit
    USIDR = data;
    // Transmit the byte (8 bits)
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // Toggle clock pin
        USICR = (1<<USIWM0) | (1<<USITC);
        // USICLK is data register clock which puts the next bit on the DO/MISO pin
        // Toggle clock pin and register counter
        USICR = (1<<USIWM0) | (1<<USICLK) | (1<<USITC);
    }
}
```

So, now I think I have a grasp at fundamentally writing values with SPI over USI on the ATTINY85 to the MCP23S08, but the tutorial doesn't go into "reading" from SPI. How would a function like `uint8_t ReadSPI(uint8_t data)` look like?

I think I got somewhere a little later. I got it to "work", but only for a short period of time. I've also added some function to set the pull up resistors, but with them off or on, this new problem keeps happening. If I use this new code, it will only run for about a couple seconds and then lock up. My USBTiny Programmer also loses connectivity. If I unplug my USBTiny (which is also powering the breadboard), and plug it back in, it will die and the attiny85 will lock up. If I unplug my USBTiny and unplug my MISO/PB1 pin and plug in everything else, my USBTiny doesn't die, and my attiny85 continues to be responsive, but is no longer talking to the MCP23S08. If I reprogram my code back to the above stated code (no reading), and plug everything back in, it works great, never loses response or anything.

It's like my "ReadSPI" function is blowing out my attiny85 and USBTiny programmer. Am I doing anything incorrectly?

Anyways, here's my code:

````
/* ATMEL ATTINY85
   Pin 1 is /RESET
   
              +-\/-+
   ADC0 PB5  1|    |8  Vcc
   ADC3 PB3  2|    |7  PB2 ADC1 INT0
   ADC2 PB4  3|    |6  PB1 OCR0B
        GND  4|    |5  PB0 OCR0A
              +----+

   PB0 = MOSI
   PB1 = MISO
   PB2 = MOSI
   PB3 = CS
   
   MCP23S08
              +-\/-+
        SCK  1|    |18  VDD
       MOSI  2|    |17  GP7
       MISO  3|    |16  GP6
         A1  4|    |15  GP5
         A0  5|    |14  GP4
     !RESET  6|    |13  GP3
        !CS  7|    |12  GP2
        INT  8|    |11  GP1
        VSS  9|    |10  GP0
              +----+
   
   SCK on MCP23S08, PB2/SCK on ATTINY85
   MOSI on MCP23S08, PB1/MISO on ATTINY85
   MISO on MCP23S08, PB0/MOSI on ATTINY85
   A1 on GND
   A0 on GND
   !RESET on 5V
   !CS on PB3 on ATTINY85
   INT unused
   VSS on GND
   VDD on 5V
   LED on MCP23S08, GP0
   Button on MCP23S08, GP7
*/

#define F_CPU 1000000UL // Setting micro to 1MHz

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// MCP23S08 Registers (Table 1-2)
#define MCP23S08_IODIR      0x00
#define MCP23S08_IPOL       0x01
#define MCP23S08_GPINTEN    0x02
#define MCP23S08_DEFVAL     0x03
#define MCP23S08_INTCON     0x04
#define MCP23S08_IOCON      0x05
#define MCP23S08_GPPU       0x06
#define MCP23S08_INTF       0x07
#define MCP23S08_INTCAP     0x08
#define MCP23S08_GPIO       0x09
#define MCP23S08_OLAT       0x0A
#define MCP23S08_WRITE_REG  0x40    // 0 1 0 0 0 A1 A0 W, b01000000 or 0x40, see figure 1-5
#define MCP23S08_READ_REG   0x41    // 0 1 0 0 0 A1 A0 R, b01000001 or 0x41, see figure 1-5


// SS or CS (Slave Select or Chip Select)
#define SS_PIN PB3
#define DD_SS_PIN DDB3

// DO or MISO (Data Out, Master In Slave Out)
#define DO_PIN PB1
#define DD_DO_PIN DDB1

// DI or MOSI (Data In, Master Out Slave In)
#define DI_PIN PB0
#define DD_DI_PIN DDB0

// CLK (Clock)
#define CLK_PIN PB2
#define DD_CLK_PIN DDB2

void SPISetUp(void);
void setGPIO(uint8_t data);
void setIODIR(uint8_t data);
void setPUR(uint8_t data);
void WriteSPI(uint8_t data);
uint8_t ReadSPI(uint8_t reg);

uint8_t mcp23s08_addr = 0x00;   // A0 is ground, A1 is ground

int main(void) {
    uint8_t button;
    uint8_t mcp23s08_port = 0x00;           // set port to off
    uint8_t mcp23s08_direction = 0xff;      // make all GPIO pins be inputs (high bits)
    uint8_t mcp23s08_pur = 0x00;
    
    mcp23s08_addr = (mcp23s08_addr << 1);   // shift address over by 1 as the first bit is the R/W bit (see figure 1-5)
    
    mcp23s08_direction |= (1 << 7);         // make GPIO 7 be an input (high bit)
    mcp23s08_direction &= ~(1 << 0);        // make GPIO 0 be an output (low bit)
    
    mcp23s08_pur |= (1 << 7);           // Set bit 7 to high to enable pull-up on GPIO 7
    
    SPISetUp();
    setIODIR(mcp23s08_direction);       // make GPIO pins be outputs
    setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);             // turn off LED
    // setPUR(mcp23s08_pur);                // set the Pull Up Resistors
    
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) {
        /*
        button = ReadSPI(MCP23S08_GPIO);
        
        if(button & (1 << 7)) {
            mcp23s08_port |= (1 << 0);  // Set bit 0 to high to turn on GPIO 0
            setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn on LED
        } else {
            mcp23s08_port &= ~(1 << 0); // Set bit 0 to low to turn off GPIO 0
            setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn off LED
        }
        */
        mcp23s08_port |= (1 << 0);  // Set bit 0 to high to turn on GPIO 0
        setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn on LED
        _delay_ms(500);
        mcp23s08_port &= ~(1 << 0); // Set bit 0 to low to turn off GPIO 0
        setGPIO(mcp23s08_port);     // turn off LED
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}

void SPISetUp() {
    // outputs
    DDRB |= (1<<DD_DO_PIN) | (1<<DD_SS_PIN) | (1<<DD_CLK_PIN);
    
    // inputs
    DDRB &= ~(1<<DD_DI_PIN);
    
    // SPI Config
    USICR = (1<<USIWM0);    // USIWM1 0, USIWM0 1 is SPI
    
    // SS_PIN on, and DI_PIN enable pull-up
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN) | (1<<DI_PIN);
}

void setIODIR(uint8_t data) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_WRITE_REG | mcp23s08_addr);   // Slave Address
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_IODIR);       // IODIR Address
    WriteSPI(data);                 // IODIR Direction
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
}

void setGPIO(uint8_t data) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_WRITE_REG | mcp23s08_addr);   // Slave Address
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_GPIO);        // GPIO Address
    WriteSPI(data);                 // GPIO Values (0 or 1, ON or OFF)
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
}

void setPUR(uint8_t data) {
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_WRITE_REG | mcp23s08_addr);   // Slave Address
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_GPPU);        // GPIO Address
    WriteSPI(data);                 // GPIO Values (0 or 1, ON or OFF)
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
}

void WriteSPI(uint8_t data) {
    // Load USI Data Register with data to transmit
    USIDR = data;
    
    // Transmit the byte (8 bits)
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // Toggle clock pin
        USICR = (1<<USIWM0) | (1<<USITC);
        // USICLK is data register clock which puts the next bit on the DO/MISO pin
        // Toggle clock pin and register counter
        USICR = (1<<USIWM0) | (1<<USICLK) | (1<<USITC);
    }
}

uint8_t ReadSPI(uint8_t reg) {
    uint8_t read_data = 0;
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS_PIN);                          // Select Slave
    WriteSPI(MCP23S08_READ_REG | mcp23s08_addr);    // Slave Address
    // _delay_ms(10);
    WriteSPI(reg);                                  // GPIO Address
    // _delay_ms(10);
    WriteSPI(0x00);                                 // Send Dummy Transmission for reading data
    // _delay_ms(10);
    read_data = USIDR;
    // _delay_ms(10);
    PORTB |= (1<<SS_PIN);           // Deselect Slave
    return read_data;
}
```
````

Comment: So, now I got it to "read", but only for a short moment. Not sure if I am overloading the attiny85 or something. Maybe killing its SRAM or something?